# how to install nagios plugin for icinga2 - Windows

Tags: nagios, icinga2

I tried to install nagios plugin for icinga2 client on windows 10.

1. Downloaded source code for nagios plugin.
2. /configure in command prompt

i got the following error

> checking whether it is possible to resort to fread on /etc/mnttab...
>   no.
>
> Configure error : could not determine how to read list of mounted file systems.

could anyone help me to fix this error.